# Parse email body paragragh in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, outlook

I am creating a script to parse outlook email body, so that I can get say an (ID number, date, name) after strings `ID: xxxxxx Date: xxxxxx Name:xxxxx`. I was looking around and could not fine anything that allows me to take the string after a match.

What I manage so far is to query for the email that was send by the specific users from outlook.

```
    Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    $inbox =                 $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
    foreach ($items in $inbox.items){if (($items.to -like "*email*") -or ($items.cc -like "*email.add*")){$FindID = $items.body}}
```

Now that I have the email body in the for loop I am wondering how I can parse the content?

In between the paragraphs will be a text something like this

```
ID: xxxxxxxx
Name: xxxxxxxxx
Date Of Birth : xxxxxxxx
```

I did some testing on the below to see if I can add that into the for loop but it seem like I cannot break the paragraphs.

```
$FindID| ForEach-Object {if (($_ -match 'ID:') -and ($_ -match ' ')){$testID = ($_ -split 'ID: ')[1]}}
```

I get the following results which I cannot get just the ID.

Sample Result when i do $testID

```
xxxxxxxx
 Name: xxxxxxxxx 
 Date Of Birth : xxxxxxxx

 Regards,
 xxxxx xxxxx
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How do I get just the results I want? I am just struggling at that portion.

Comment: Do you want just the values, say xxxxxxxx, in 3 different strings in an array, or do you also want the Name, ID and Date part?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I want the 3 xxxxxxx value for now, I am thinking of exporting it into a CSV files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a Regular Expression with (named) capture groups to grep the values. [See example on rexgex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1B2rD1/1).
Provdid `$item.body`is not html and a single string, this could work:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\24\SO_51492907.ps1
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
## see $RE on https://regex101.com/r/1B2rD1/1
$RE = [RegEx]'(?sm)ID:\s+(?<ID>.*?)$.*?Name:\s+(?<Name>.*?)$.*?Date Of Birth\s*:\s*(?<DOB>.*?)$.*'

$Data = ForEach ($item in $inbox.items){
    if (($item.to -like "*email*") -or 
        ($item.cc -like "*email.add*")){
        if (($item.body -match $RE )){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ID   = $Matches.ID
                Name = $Matches.Name
                DOB  = $Matches.DOB
            }
        }
    }
}
$Data 
$Data | Export-CSv '.\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output with above anonimized mail

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\24\SO_51492907.ps1

ID        Name       DOB
--        ----       ---
xxxxxx... xxxxxxx... xxxxxx...
```

Comment: I did not see your comment before, thank you for this and link to Regex website.

Comment: Modified answer to gather information in variable `$Data` and export it to `.\data.csv` in current folder.

Comment: Thank you for the modification, this work really well.. I notice there are some email where it went.

email: xxxxxxxxx accidentally copied over some text

It will capture everything and break the above regex chain by collecting more data. How do I end the string if I want it to stop at the end?

Comment: Well,you weren't specific what the lines contain (`xxxxxx..`), so the RegEx anchors at the respective line end `$`.  If you supply some more real world examples where it didn't work well by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51492907/edit) your question,  the simple `(.*?)$` part could be refined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted to learn Powershell myself that's why I threw a more generic example for the above use case. Right Now I am just toying around with multiple scenarios that I have encountered. Would you prefer I edit the question or post it here?

Comment: I manage solve the above questions, thanks a lot for the website.

Comment: To learn more about Regular Expressions I recommend [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Outlook available at the moment, but i think this will work

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$inbox.items | Where-Object { $_.To -like "*email*" -or $_.CC -like "*email.add*"} {
    $body = $_.body
    if ($body -match '(?s)ID\s*:\s*(?<id>.+)Name\s*:\s*(?<name>.+)Date Of Birth\s*:\s*(?<dob>\w+)') {
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Subject'        = $_.Subject
            'Date Received'  = ([datetime]$_.ReceivedTime).ToString()
            'ID'             = $matches['id']
            'Name'           = $matches['name']
            'Date of Birth'  = $matches['dob']

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, This looks really complicated with all the Regex, anywhere I can read up on this?

Comment: Folllowing the `where {}` block is a `| ForEach` missing, otherwise your answer is quite similar to mine.

Comment: @LotPings Damn, you're right. I didn't spot that!. When i added my answer i saw the screen refreshing with your answer in it. You beat me to it by 9 seconds or so ;)